# Google Sheets formula calculating time past mid-night

Tags: google-sheets, time, google-sheets-formula

We track working hours in google sheets by having each person specify the start time and end time in a single cell.

Example:
1330 - 2230

From there we calculate their hours using this formula

```
=IF(HK81:81 <> "",IFERROR((TIMEVALUE(LEFT(right(HK81:81,4),2)&":"&right(RIGHT(HK81:81,4),2))-TIMEVALUE(left(left(HK81:81,4),2)&":"&RIGHT(left(HK81:81,4),2)))*24-1,0),"")
```

Problem:
We have one agent whose shift ends at 2400 (midnight): 1500-2400. However, this generates -16 for hours instead of 8.

The solutions I've seen online seem to be for situations where start time and end time are in separate cells.

Question:
How can we edit the formula for people whose shift ends at 2400.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap [ABS](https://www.liveflow.io/product-guides/how-to-use-abs-formula-in-google-sheets) around your subtraction:

```
=IF(HK81:81 <> "",IFERROR(ABS(TIMEVALUE(LEFT(right(HK81:81,4),2)&":"&right(RIGHT(HK81:81,4),2))-TIMEVALUE(left(left(HK81:81,4),2)&":"&RIGHT(left(HK81:81,4),2)))*24-1,0),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

* Note that you're providing a range to your functions but they are not array-enabled so hour formula is only seeing the *first cell*, which is `HK81`.

Said that, here's what you can try:

```
=LET(end,   REGEXREPLACE(HK81,".*(\d\d)(\d\d)","$1:$2"),
     start, REGEXREPLACE(HK81,"(\d\d)(\d\d).*","$1:$2"),
     end - start + (end < start))
```

In the first two lines we are extracting the `end` and `start` times (respectively) while simultaneously adding a colon `:` in between.

In the third line, we are subtracting the `start` time from the `end` time and adding `1` (which corresponds to 24 hours) IF the `end` time is less than the `start` time and `0` otherwise.